# NodeJS app works locally but crashes on Heroku

Tags: http, heroku, deployment, proxy

I have problem with my application, which is normally working locally, but when I deploy it on Heroku, then it crashes.

My repo: https://github.com/gkucmierz/cors-proxy

Answer (score 0):

If you search for:

node.js deploy to heroku

You will find that there are certain restrictions to uploading a node.js on heroku.
You should include an application.yml file.
You should include a procfile.
You should modify any interactions with databases to work with postgresql.

I hope I could help.

Comment: I dont use database in my project.

Comment: I think heroku ENV_VARS like node = "prod" may change http module behaviour
I am not sure, what may be the best solution

Comment: AFAIK I dont need procfile cause this line ```"start": "node src/index.js"``` in package.json does the job

Comment: Yes one thing I forgot to mention is that the port number should also be changed to match the port on the heroku app, I believe it is mentioned on the website.

Comment: Please check source I have shared with you https://github.com/gkucmierz/cors-proxy/blob/master/src/index.js#L5
to not solve problem that not exist for me